# How do change the text file such that it will consist of multiple lines?

Tags: java, file, input, file-io, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that has the following contents.
I was trying to test my code out, and noticed the file I input for my scanner consist of only one line. Why is that so?, when I open the text file it appears it has multiple lines.

When I open this is excel, it shows multiple lines However when I program this, it would show all of this consist in one line. How can I change this file structure such that it will have multiple rows

text file:

```
categories
Fast Food;Restaurants
Nightlife
Active Life;Mini Golf;Golf
Bars;American (New);Nightlife;Lounges;Restaurants
Active Life;Golf
Bars;American (Traditional);Nightlife;Restaurants
Auto Repair;Automotive;Tires
Active Life;Mini Golf
Roofing;Home Services;Decks & Railing;Contractors
Veterinarians;Pets
Libraries;Public Services & Government
Automotive;Auto Parts & Supplies
Burgers;Breakfast & Brunch;American (Traditional);Restaurants
Food;Grocery
Automotive;Gas & Service Stations
Local Services;Dry Cleaning & Laundry;Sewing & Alterations
Automotive;Gas & Service Stations
Bars;American (Traditional);Nightlife;Lounges;Restaurants
Breakfast & Brunch;Sandwiches;Restaurants
Cafes;Restaurants
Hotels & Travel;Event Planning & Services;Hotels
Pubs;Irish;Nightlife;Bars;Restaurants
Pizza;Restaurants
Local Services;Sewing & Alterations
Restaurants
Health & Medical;Dentists;General Dentistry
Chinese;Restaurants
Veterinarians;Pets
```

code:

```
public class TestScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/data/test3.txt"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(";");
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.print(scanner.nextLine());
            count++;

        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

Output: 1

Comment: Your code it is just fine. I suspect your test3 file is has just one empty line. Please verify this.

Comment: Maybe your text editor is using word wrap. Open your txt file on notepad++ and go to view > symbols > show all characters. This will show you whether your file contains record delimiter characters, i.e. \n (LF) or \r\n (CRLF).

Comment: your code works fine!!

Comment: @rafaelbattesti He is printing the lines, so in case of word wrapping it should still print at least one big line. That's not the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You don't to change the text file. Probably you need to change the code. Try this:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:/data/test3.txt");
LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
String tmp = null;
while ((tmp = lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null) {
    count++;
    System.out.println(tmp);
}

lineNumberReader.close();
System.out.println(count);
```

It will treat the text file as multiple line text.

Comment: I guess OP's problem is in text file. If you don't have the text in multiple lines in the file, your method is not going to work. Otherwise any reader can serve OP's need.

Comment: @WasiAhmad I ran the OP's code and the text file. And indeed it gave me one line. Then I changed the code with exactly the same text input and it gave multiple lines. By the way, the text file is in multiple lines.

Comment: I ran OP's code and it worked perfectly and yes the text file needs to contain multiple lines.

Comment: @WasiAhmad And? I gave a possible solution.

Comment: I meant to say if there is a problem (doesn't contain multiple lines) in the text file, no method is going to work. If the file contains multiple lines, there are lot of alternatives but OP doesn't need that because OP's solution is already working!!

Comment: @WasiAhmad You are adding unnecessary if condition - if the text file contains one line. The OP's file contain MULTIPLE LINES. And I say again - I ran the OP's code and it gave one line in the output. I proposed a possible workaround which gave multiple lines in the output with exactly the same input text. That's it. Conversation is over. You are not constructive at all.